# Laravel throwing error only in production mode

Tags: php, laravel, caching, production

When i switch the debug APP_LOG_LEVEL to production throwing this error

`production.ERROR: Call to undefined method Closure::__set_state() {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to undefined method Closure::__set_state() at /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/saas/bootstrap/cache/config.php:1073)`

Im not even caching config files. There is no /bootstrap/cache/config.php file! And even weirder this error occurrs only in production mode!

Comment: which framework  use?
do you ever run this command `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: Delete the cache for config.

It is located in here

`bootstrap/cache/config.php`
OR
`vendor/config.php`

Comment: thank you for answers. 

but we solved the problem. actually the problem was caused by former programmer. He thought adding config folder to gitignore would be a good practice but obviously its not..

Comment: :))))))))))))))))))